# Redux Reducers error when I use combineReducer method

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I am trying to integrate Redux-Persist to my react app.
I am using Redux currently for state management and had no issues when I used `configureStore` and added my reducers to it.
But, when I use the `combineReducer()` method with the same reducers to setup my Redux-Persist I get this error:

> "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object
> of functions that can be passed to combineReducers

This is how I configured `redux-persist`:

configureStore.js:

```js
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"; // defaults to localStorage for web

import rootReducers from "./reducers";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducers);

export default () => {
  let store = configureStore(persistedReducer);
  let persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor };
};
```

This is my reducers file:

```js
import fetchingReducer from "./fetchingProductsSlice";
import LoadingErrorReducer from "./Loading-ErrorSlice";
import authReducer from "./AuthSlice";
import cartReducer from "./CartSlice";
import favReduer from "./Fav/FavSlice";
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export default rootReducers = combineReducers({
  products: fetchingReducer,
  loadingerror: LoadingErrorReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
  fav: favReduer,
});
```

Example of how I built my reducers:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  cartItems: [],
  isAdded: false,
};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getCartItems(state, action) {
      state.cartItems = action.payload;
    },
    setIsAdded(state, action) {
      state.isAdded = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { getCartItems, setIsAdded } = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./Store/Store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import pers from "./Store/configureStore";

const { persistor } = pers();

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I tired to add the action type in switch like this but I got the same error:

```js
reducers: {
  getCartItems(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "getCartItems":
        state.cartItems = action.payload;
    }
  },
  setIsAdded(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "setIsAdded":
        state.isAdded = action.payload;
    }
  }
;

export const { getCartItems, setIsAdded } = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

I don't know if the issue is in how I created my reducers or is elsewhere.

Comment: `let store = configureStore({ reducer: persistedReducer });`

Answer (score 0):

The `configureStore` is a bit different from the older deprecated `createStore` function of "legacy" Redux. Instead of taking an array of arguments like `createStore`, `configureStore` takes a single `options` argument. `reducer` is one of these options properties, and is the only ***required*** property, the rest are optional.

See [`configureStore` parameters](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#parameters) for details.

> ```
> interface ConfigureStoreOptions<
>   S = any,
>   A extends Action = AnyAction,
>   M extends Middlewares<S> = Middlewares<S>
> > {
>   reducer: Reducer<S, A> | ReducersMapObject<S, A>
>   middleware?: ((getDefaultMiddleware: CurriedGetDefaultMiddleware<S>) => M) | M
>   devTools?: boolean | DevToolsOptions
>   preloadedState?: DeepPartial<S extends any ? S : S>
>   enhancers?: StoreEnhancer[] | ConfigureEnhancersCallback
> }
> ```

To fix your your code, pass an options object with the required `reducer` property that is your configured persisted reducer function:

```js
let store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
});
```